# curves messed up when converting ggplot2 to plotly using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have 100 kinds of polymers and each polymer has 20 data points (x, y) to plot a curve. I used R Shiny to interactively select one or more polymers to plot. Everything works fine when I used ggplot2 to plot. Since plotly is able to do tooltip, I converted ggplot2 to plotly using something like

```
p = ggplot(subdata, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = polymer) + geom_line() + geom_point() + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10() +  theme() 
ggplotly(p)
```

Now problem happens. Every time once I selected a certain polymer (call it BadGuy), the curves mess up.

Before selecting BadGuy, the curves are neat.
[Before selecting BadGuy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVZ3Z.png)

But after selecting BadGuy, the curves messed up. 
[After selecting BadGuy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FxeX.png)

Everything works fine if just using ggplot2, no matter selecting or not selecting the BadGuy. I guess it is the convert causing this problem, but I do not know how to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your input data? Otherwise it is really hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: I figured it out later. I have to sort the data before plotting using plotly even though it is not necessary for ggplot2.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer. It might be helpful for someone else searching for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out later. I have to sort the data before plotting using plotly even though it is not necessary for ggplot2